# flutter streams bloc to show handle visible state

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, bloc

I have a widget `isLive` that changes state based on the value returned by the bloc.However everytime i run the app i get

> The getter 'progressStateStream' was called on null

I tried following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57658974/10409567)

```
 Widget isLive() {
    return Container(
        child: StreamBuilder<bool>(
      stream: _bloc.progressStateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        return Visibility(
          maintainState: true,
          visible: snapshot.data ?? false,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.pink[50],
              height: 50,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[

                  Text("yaay i'm visible"),

                  RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    child: Text(
                      "hide"
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {
                      _bloc.changeProgressState(state: false);
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
```

here is my bloc

```
  //this Subject allows sending data, error and done events to the listener
  final PublishSubject<bool> _progressStateSubject = new PublishSubject();

  //the listener are streaming on changes
  Observable<bool> get progressStateStream => _progressStateSubject.stream;

  //to change your progress state
  void changeProgressState({bool state}) => _progressStateSubject.sink.add(state);
```

Also if i wanted to save state with hydrated bloc how would I go about it

Comment: Where is your init state?

Comment: I haven't initialized it in my init state

Comment: The message mean the `_bloc` are null. So please so me where did you input the instance of `_bloc`.

Comment: managed to solve it by initialising my bloc in init state thanks `_bloc = RBloc();
      _bloc.progressStateStream;`

Comment: Plz update your question solution by a new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by initialising my bloc in init state by adding the bloc to init state

```
_bloc = RBloc();
 _bloc.progressStateStream;
```